# Power Automate 'Create CSV Table' from SharePoint list fails: from property is 'object' but must be 'array'

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have a flow designed to pull data (multiple rows) from a SharePoint list, create a CSV table from it, then create a CSV file from that CSV table. After my Get Items, within an Apply to Each section, I set a number of variables and then want to use the Create CSV Table action to compile the values to be written into the file.

The Create CSV Table action is generating an error, though:

> BadRequest. The 'from' property value in the 'table' action inputs is of type 'Object'. The value must be of type 'Array'.

Here's my overall flow:
[full flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soVc1.png)

Here's the Apply to Each section, including how the Create CSV Table action is set up:
[apply to each section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcBAW.png)

Am I using the Create CSV Table action incorrectly? Do I need an intermediate step where I construct an array within my Apply to Each section, and then populate the Create CSV Table action outside of the Apply to Each, using the output of the array? If so... I've never done that before and am not sure how to go about it: can anyone get me started? Or is there another issue?

I've tried adjusting the Value items in my Create CSV Table action, but they are still clearly objects and not arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Create CSV Table** is looking for an 'Array' instead of an 'Object within an Array' (which is what is happening as it is within the **Apply to each** control)

Add a **Select** step right after **Get items** to select the columns which you want (i.e. Column Mapping) and to output an **array**.

The **Create CSV table** step can follow afterwards. There is no need for an **Apply To Each** control.

[image]

Comment: Thank you: I'll try this and report back. For the other actions I apply for each of my "get items" items (set a variable, update that list item, send an email), do they still need to be in the apply to each block, or should they be after as well? I had the impression that "apply to each" looped, but then anything after that just ran once after all the "apply to each" loops had finished, in which case even if I had 30 items selected in my "get items" action I'd only send an email or do an update item for the last one. Was I wrong in that, or does the Select operation work differently?

Comment: I have tested and can confirm that this works correctly. I kept the other components within the Apply to Each container, but moved the Select, Create CSV Table, and Create File blocks after the Apply to Each and it works as expected.

Comment: @Darryl Great to know it works!